# "System.JSONException: Type cannot be serialized" error in a dynamic call across managed packages

Tags: apex, managed-package, json, serialization, managed-extension

We have two managed packages. One is a core package and another is an extension package. From the core package, we are trying to call a Global Batch Apex Class dynamically. When we try to pass a Set  of parameters to the Extension Package Batch Apex Class using serialization, we get the error: **System.JSONException: Type cannot be serialized**

Note: when I remove the parameters, I can call the batch apex just fine.

Code Snippet from Core Package:

```
set <ID> actionids= new set <ID>();
actionids.add('a1j6s000000Iy4BAAS');

Type t = Type.forName('owsxas.batchPostResults');
Database.batchable<sObject> instance = (Database.batchable<sObject>)t.newInstance();
Map<String, Object> variableMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(instance));
variableMap.put('actionID', actionids);

system.debug(variableMap);
instance = (Database.Batchable<sObject>)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(variableMap), t);
Database.executeBatch(instance, 10);
```

Global Batch Apex Class from Extension Package:

```
global class batchPostResults implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful{ 

    private Set <Id > actionID;

    global batchPostResults(Set<Id> aID){
        actionID = aID;
    }
    
    global batchPostResults (){
     
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query;
            query = 'Select ID FROM owsc__Action__c where ID IN: actionID';

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.batchableContext BC, owsc__Action__c[] scope){
        //do stuff
    }

    global void finish(Database.batchableContext info){

    }

}
```

Any ideas on this? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just do `Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(new Map<String, Object>{ 'actionID' => actionids}, t);`?

Comment: Some points to note: 1. `JSON.deserialize` does not invoke any constructors, 2. Only the class itself needs to be `global` to be instantiable across a namespace boundary; the `Batchable` methods can be `public` since they are introduced by the Salesforce interface and 3. Batchables must be top-level (not nested) classes otherwise you get an error on execution.

Comment: @PhilW , thank you!

I tried the snippet you gave me and now getting this error. `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(Map<String,Object>, System.Type) from the type System.JSON`
set <ID> actionIDs = new set <ID>();
actionids.add('a1j6s000000Iy4BAAS');
Type t = Type.forName('owsxas.batchPostResultsToAcctSeed');
`Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(new Map<String, Object>{ 'actionID' => actionids}, t));`

Comment: Sorry, I should have put a serialise around the new Map to turn it into a JSON string.

Comment: @PhilW Unfortunately, now receiving a `System.JSONException: Type cannot be deserialized
` error. The line looks good to me... any other ideas? `Database.executeBatch((Database.Batchable<SObject>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{ 'actionID' => actionids}), t));` Thank you for all your help.

Comment: It is very odd. We have packaged code that uses Type.forName and JSON deserialization to instantiate Batchable implementations in an almost identical manner. We even have Batchables holding Set instances. I wonder if it is actually bad ID data? Your example has hard-coded IDs, but what does the real code use to get the IDs?

Comment: @PhilW yes I was only using the hardcode as an example, the managed package gets the IDs from the UI. Right now I'm just testing it through Anonymous Window. I even grabbed IDs using a query and list. Still getting error... Good to know that you are using the same implementation. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: So let's check: the batch class is defined outside the package and instantiated in packaged code dynamically, yes? The batch is defined as `global` and the `actionID` property is `private`. Can you try turning `actionID` into a `List<Id>` instead of a `Set`? While we do use `Set` this isn't initialized from JSON.

Comment: @PhilW yes your assumption is correct. We dynamically call from our Base Package to our Extension Package (where the batchable apex exists). I changed the Set to a List and same error regarding `System.JSONException: Type cannot be deserialized`.